# Не выводит параметры в форму

Tags: ajax, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, jpa

Пишу легковесную кмс для саморазвития.
Не хочет выводить параметры в форму -

```js
 if (document.getElementById("license_key_first")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/cp/first",
            success: function (info) {
                $("#key_first").html(info.key_first);
            }
        });
    }
```

Данные получаю из таблицы, проставил бряки, сервер получает все что нужно из БД.

Код контроллера -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/cp")
public class UserCpController {
@Autowired
private UserCpService service;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/first")
public String getLicenseKeyFirst(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsDecorator currentUser) {
    return retriveText(service.getLicenseKeyFirst(currentUser.getEntity()).key_first);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/second")
public String getLicenseKeySecond(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsDecorator currentUser) {
    return retriveText(service.getLicenseKeySecond(currentUser.getEntity()).key_second);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/period")
public Timestamp getLicensePeriod(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsDecorator currentUser) {
    return service.getLicensePeriod(currentUser.getEntity()).period;
}

private String retriveText(String text) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        final char ch = text.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isHighSurrogate(ch) && !Character.isLowSurrogate(ch)) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Код сервиса -

```
@Service
public class UserCpService {
@Autowired
private TblAccountRepository pcRepository;

public CpLicenseInfo getLicenseKeyFirst(TblAccountEntity entity) {
    final CpLicenseInfo info = new CpLicenseInfo();
    info.key_first = pcRepository.findBycAccId(entity.getcAccId()).getcLicenseKeyFirst();
    return info;
}

public CpLicenseInfo getLicenseKeySecond(TblAccountEntity entity) {
    final CpLicenseInfo info = new CpLicenseInfo();
    info.key_second = pcRepository.findBycAccId(entity.getcAccId()).getcLicenseKeySecond();
    return info;
}

public CpLicenseInfo getLicensePeriod(TblAccountEntity entity) {
    final CpLicenseInfo info = new CpLicenseInfo();
    info.period = pcRepository.findBycAccId(entity.getcAccId()).getcLicensePeriod();
    return info;
}
}
```

Pojo информации -

```
public class CpLicenseInfo {
public String key_first;
public String key_second;
public Timestamp period;
}
```

Код модуля куда передаются параметры -

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="license_key_first">
    <tr>
        <th>Key: <strong id="key_first"/></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: "Не хочет выводить" - а что хочет? Что происходит-то? Код `$("#key_first").html(info.key_first);` выполняется?

Comment: @igor по всей видимости нет, маппер выводит в лог что key передан на страницу но собственно никакого результата. Я беру из базы ключ для юзера и пытаюсь его вывести в <strong id="key_first"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено отправкой на "клиент-сайд" pojo в json

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/first")
public @ResponseBody CpLicenseInfo getLicenseKeyFirst(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsDecorator currentUser) {
    return service.getLicenseKeyFirst(currentUser.getEntity());
}

if (document.getElementById("license_key_first")) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/cp/first",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.key_first;
            $("#key_first").text(result);
        }
    });
}
```